# Overriding a method which returns Unit while writing unit test cases

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing unit test cases using MockitoSugar.

Here is my sample code:

```
class EmployeeRepo {

  def addEmplyees(emp:Employee): Long = {
    //logic
    val res1 = sendReport
    val res2 = sendNotification
    //logic
  }

  def sendReport:Boolean={
    //logic
  }

  def sendNotification:Unit={
    //logic
  }
}
```

Sample test case:

```
class TestEmployeeRepo extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar with ScalaFutures {
  "TestEmployeeRepo" must {
    "add employee" in {
      //mock statements
      val result = MockEmployeeRepo.addEmplyees(emp)
      //assert statements
    }
  }
} 

object MockEmployeeRepo extends EmployeeRepo {
  override def sendReport:Boolean = true   
  override def sendNotification:Unit = //needs unit
}
```

Here in the above piece of code I am trying to test `addEmployee` method with necessary mocking. So while overriding `sendNotification`which actually returns `Unit`, I am not sure how should I return `Unit`.

I tried these two ways:

```
override def sendNotification:Unit = println("")

override def sendNotification:Unit = Unit
```

Working fine, but please suggest me the right way to follow and what should be there at `//needs unit`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an empty block or the literal symbol for unit `()` (aka the empty tuple)

```
override def sendNotification:Unit = {}
override def sendNotification:Unit = ()
```

As you can see below, they both represent the Literal `()`

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> showRaw(reify(()))
res0: String = Expr(Literal(Constant(())))

scala> showRaw(reify({}))
res1: String = Expr(Literal(Constant(())))
```

As per Łukasz's  comment though, there is a difference: while `()` actually represents the **singleton** for the `Unit` type, the empty block is desugared into a block that only contains `()` inside.

More specifically, the compiler automatically puts the `()` for you at the end of any block that has to evaluate to `Unit`. You already noticed this here:

```
override def sendNotification:Unit = println("")
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that empty block represents `()` I mean effectively it's the same, but conceptually `()` is the only value of `Unit` type and compiler puts it automatically in the end of block that is supposed to be evaluated to type `Unit`. `def a: Unit = {println(1); 2 + 2 }` would be translated to `def a: Unit = {println(1); 2 + 2; () }`. I just wanted to clarify for OP that there is no magic making `{}` and `()` equivalent. Just a general rule that does this in this specific case.

Comment: you are right, I'll refine my answer in a while

Answer (score 1):

You can use `()`, which is the literal value for Unit type.

```
override def sendNotification: Unit = ()
```